# How can different data is transferred from the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

client is esp32cam(camera module)
It is send Image to app.js every 3seconds

app.js

```
client.on("message", async(topic, message)=>{ // {"LED" : "ON"} or {"MOTER" : "ON"}
    if(topic == "JPG")
    {
        var obj = message.toString();
        app.get("/img", function(req,res,next){
            res.set("content-Type", "text/json");
            //res.send(JSON.stringify({data : obj}));
            res.json({
                data: obj || "no image yet"
            });
            console.log(obj);//number 1
        });
        console.log(obj);//number 2
    }
}
```

number 1 is print same data every 3seconds

number 2 is print different data every 3seconds

how can number1 print different data each time??

html

```
$(function() {
            timer = setInterval( function () {
            console.log("timer")
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ip:3000/img",
                type: "get",
                context : this,
                cache : false,
                error : function(request,status,error){
                    console.log("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
                },
                success:function(obj){
                    $("#imguri").html('<img src="'+obj.data+'">');
                    $("#imguri").attr("src", obj.data);
                    console.log("mqtt in " + obj.data);
                    // console.log("TEST");

                }
            });
            }, 3000);
});
```

my problem
[image]

[image]

Comment: what does it log? can you add it to the post?

Comment: yes it is data uri

Comment: The code doesn't make sense, why are you adding a new http route on every message? The on `message` callback should be storing the new image in a global variable and the route should just return the global variable.

Comment: Also it would be easier/cleaner to just deliver the image directly to a JavaScript MQTT client running in the page via MQTT over WebSockets.

Comment: you are a genius thanks very much I just solved this problem with global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are stacking multiple `app.get("/img",...)` routes (one for every incoming message).

Only the first one will ever be called, so the HTTP client will always just get the very first image.

You should make the MQTT client callback store the new image in a global variable and then just have one instance of the `/img` route return that global variable.

```
var img;
client.on("message", async(topic, message)=>{ // {"LED" : "ON"} or {"MOTER" : "ON"}
  if(topic == "JPG")
  {
    var obj = message.toString();
    img = obj
  }
}

app.get("/img", function(req,res,next){
  res.set("content-Type", "text/json");
  res.json({
    data: img || "no image yet"
  });
  console.log(obj);//number 1
});
```